# Weld producer methods not injecting - NPE

Tags: java, cdi, weld

I am trying to create a simple example of using classes that have producer methods, with the aim that the producer method injects the dependency instead of Weld trying to create the bean. Which is why I've `@Vetoed` the `DefaultEngine` I also wish to stick with the `@Default @Any` qualifiers

So I have the following

Engine.java

```
public interface Engine
{
    void start();
    void stop();
}
```

DefaultEngine.java

```
@Vetoed
public class DefaultEngine implements Engine
{

    public void start()
    {
        System.out.println("Cough cough vrummmmm");
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        System.out.println("Phhhut clank");
    }

}
```

Car.java

```
public class Car
{
    @Inject
    private Engine engine;

    public void startCar()
    {
        engine.start();
    }

    public void stopCar()
    {
        engine.stop();
    }

}
```

App.java

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main(@Observes ContainerInitialized event)
    {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.startCar();
        car.stopCar();
    }
}
```

EngineProducer.java

```
public class EngineProducer
{

    @Produces
    public Engine getEngine()
    {
        return new DefaultEngine();
    }

}
```

And I have the beans.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd">
</beans>
```

But it seems the `Engine` is not injected as I receive the following.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.testing.Car.startCar(Car.java:12)
    at com.test.testing.App.main(App.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:129)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:308)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:274)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:264)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:271)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:136)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:673)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer.initialize(WeldContainer.java:142)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:544)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.StartMain.go(StartMain.java:44)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.StartMain.main(StartMain.java:53)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK found the answer, it appears Weld cannot manage beans created with new also it cannot inject bean instances into observers of container events. So the main App.java has to change to

```
public class App 
{
    @Inject
    private Car car;

    public void main(@Observes ContainerInitialized event)
    {
        car.startCar();
        car.stopCar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, when you instantiate an object of your own using the new-operator, it is under your control. Since CDI is an "Inversion-of-Control"-container, you must let CDI to create that object for you.